# How many atoms can be reduced in a single redox reaction?

Tags: redox

I am doing high school chemistry and I am busy working with redox reactions.

The explanation in my text book, of how a redox reaction works, left me a bit confused as to how many atoms can be reduced/oxidized in a single reaction equation.

Can only one atom (species) be reduced/oxidized in a single equation or can there be more than one reduced/oxidized in the same chemical equation?

All of the reaction equations I have come across so far have just one atom reduced and one atom oxidized, for example:

$$ \ce {Mg(s) + 2HCl(aq) -> H_2(g) + MgCl_2(aq)} $$

In this reaction only Mg is oxidized and only H is reduced. Is there a reaction in which more than one species of atom it reduced or oxidized?

Comment: Redox reactions can be _much_ more complicated then that.

Comment: I know they get much more complex. I am not doing very complex ones yet. I just chose a simple one to try illustrate my question, which is a very simple question.

Comment: Yes, there can be more and yes/no questions are suitable for this site.

Comment: Thanks. That really helps. I think my text book spoke as if only one could be reduced/oxidized at a time because I would not need to do more complex ones yet. Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to up-vote you :-(

Comment: I'd rather point out that the reactions in which *multiple* elements get oxidized/reduced are a relative minority (in school chemistry, at least). True, you'd encounter pretty complex reactions further on, but their complexity stems from other reasons; despite it, most of the times there would be only one oxidant and one reducing agent.

Comment: Of two species, one would usually be easier to reduce/oxidise than the other. As a reducing agent/oxidiser, I would in most cases just leave out the latter, and work on two of the former. Exemptions, as usual, prove the rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but consider the reaction

$$\ce{CH3-SH + 3 O2 -> SO2 + CO2 + 2 H2O}$$

where methanethiol is oxidized with oxygen to sulfur dioxide, carbon dioxide, and water.

Thereby the oxidation states of sulfur and carbon change from $-2$ to $+4$ and the oxidation state of oxygen from $\pm0$ to $-2$. So sulfur and carbon atoms are both oxidized while oxygen is reduced.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: @adventurin: This did answer the question, thank you. The example equation helped. By the way, any suggestions on how to make the question clearer would be appreciated.